# Covariance between previous and next occurrence.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Consider a Poisson process where the time between occurrences is random from a distribution with density function $f(t)$. Assume that we are at a random point in time $T$, so likely between two occurrences, say $O_1$ and $O_2$. Then my question is

> What is the covariance between the length of $[O_1,T]$ and the length of $[T,O_2]$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Poissons on dishjoint intervals are independent, so covariance is...

Comment: If they are independent the covariance is $0$, right? However, are they independent no matter what the density function is?

Comment: What density function?

Comment: No, it works only for memoryless $f(t)$ - without memorylessness, information will "seep" through".

Comment: @A.S. Yeah, I thought so too. Do you know how one can approach the problem with the given density?

Comment: Do you know distribution of $T$ or you just assume it's large compared to mean and standard deviation of $f$ so that we are in a "well-mixed" portion of the process?

Comment: @A.S. I'm pretty sure I can just assume that we are far enough into the process, as you say.

Comment: @A.S. why $X\sim T$? If I understand it correctly, $T=X+Y$ , no?

Comment: @Jay It's not the case that $X+Y\sim T$ (which holds only if $T$ is degenerate). The reason for this is that you are more likely to land in a long inter-arrival time than a short one. For standard Poisson we have $X,Y,T\sim \exp(1)$ for example, so $E(X+Y)=2E(T)$. In general $E(X+Y)\ge E(T)$ with equality iff $T$ is degenerate.

Comment: @A.S. I may be still mistaken about the question. But first,$T$ was used in the original post as a picked time, to avoid confusion, let's use $\tau$ to represent your T, the interarrival time. So, using the original post notations, and suppose we repeatedly draw random samples, at each time,  the length of the left interval is $X=T-O_1$ and $Y=O_2-T$ and $\tau=O_2-O_1$, so, $\tau =X+Y$ every single time.  So $E(\tau)=E(X)+E(Y)$. Any thing wrong with this argument?

Comment: @Jay What do you mean by $O_2-O_1=\tau$? $\tau$ stands for *distribution* of interarrival times, not a specific interarrival time. And as I have mentioned, $O_2-O_1\sim \tau$ only if $\tau$ is degenerate because you are not picking an interarrival period uniformly at random, but a point in such an interval which biases you towards longer intervals.

Comment: @Jay Following this reasoning yields $f_{O_2-O_1}(t)=\frac{f_{\tau}(t)t}{E(\tau)}$, hence $E(O_2-O_1)=\frac {E(\tau^2)}{E(\tau)}=E(\tau)+\frac {\sigma^2(\tau)}{E(\tau)}$.

Comment: @A.S. I see, sorry, my misunderstanding. Now, I think I understand that the length of the  right interval $Y\sim \tau$ for the Poisson case, but, still don't understand why $X\sim \tau$, can you please explain?

Comment: @Jay It doesn't matter which way you run time in Poisson process. You don't even need to "run time" for Poisson, since distribution of number of points inside *any* region $A$ depends only on size of $A$ - so the direction of time is irrelevant.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks, that's helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\tau$ be distribution of inter-arrival times and let $Z=O_2-O_1=O_2-T+(T-O_1)=Y+X$ where $X,Y|Z\sim Unif(0,Z)$. The probability of $T$ landing in an inter-arrival period of length $t$ is proportional to $tf_{\tau}(t)$, hence $$f_Z(t)=\frac {tf_{\tau}(t)}{\mu_\tau}$$

Then conditioning on $Z$ yields $$E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E(X(Z-X))-\frac 1 4 E(Z)^2=\frac 1 6E(Z^2)-\frac 1 4E(Z)^2=\frac 1 {\mu_\tau}(\frac {E(\tau^3)
}6-\frac {E(\tau^2)^2}{4\mu_\tau})$$

at the same time $$var(X)=var(Y)=E(\frac 1 {12}Z^2)+var(\frac 1 2 Z)=\frac {E(\tau^3)}{12\mu_\tau}+\frac {E(\tau^3)} {4\mu_\tau}-\frac {E(\tau^2)^2}{4\mu^2_{\tau}}=\frac 1 {\mu_\tau}(\frac {E(\tau^3)}{3}-\frac{E(\tau^2)^2}{4\mu_{\tau}})$$
Hence correlation coefficient is

$$\rho=\frac{2E(\tau^3)E(\tau)-3E(\tau^2)^2}{4E(\tau^3)E(\tau)-3E(\tau^2)^2}=\frac {2\kappa\sigma^3\mu-\mu^4-3\sigma^4}{4\kappa\sigma^3\mu+6\sigma^2\mu^2+\mu^4-3\sigma^4}=\frac{2\kappa c_v-c_v^4-3}{4\kappa c_v+6c_v^2+c_v^4-3}<\frac 1 2$$
To check correctness, plug in $\sigma=0$ to get $\rho=-1$ as expected. For $\tau$ exponential, $\kappa=2$, $c_v=1$ and $\rho=0$ as expected. We also see that by making $\kappa$ large we can approach $\rho = \frac 1 2$, but for $\kappa=0$, $\rho<0$ - as expected.

---

Since $\rho\ge -1$, we also get probabilistic proof that $$E(\tau^2)^2\le E(\tau^3)E(\tau)$$
for non-negative $\tau$.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for the answer. I have one question, and it might be simple, but how do you get

$$E[X(Z-X)] = \frac16 E(Z^2)?$$

Comment: It is from the assumption that X is evenly distributed in [0, Z], given Z.

Comment: @Jay.H Hmm.. Okay. It is just weird, because the result just does not seem to align with my simulations. It is correct to say that
$$E(Z) = \int_0^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t $$
and
$$E(Z^2) = \int_0^\infty t^2 f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t $$
right? Can we say that even though we are more likely to hit a long interval?

Comment: You should use $f_Z$ instead of $f$ in the calculation.

Comment: @Jay.H Thank you both, now I understand everything!

Comment: I have a follow up question: I think the argument relies on the assumption that T is large, so the conclusion is asymptotically true. What about when T is small? Can we derive an accurate formula?

Comment: @Jay According to which rule do you pick $T$ - especially relative to $\tau$?

Comment: How about just a constant, say, $T=1/\lambda$?

Comment: How is $\lambda$ related to $\tau$?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, $\lambda$ is the arrival intensity of $\tau$

Comment: Or more generally, $T=E(\tau)$